# Resetting graphs in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In some sample codes, we see the following code for reseting a graph:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

But I think the following more simpler function do the same:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Both point to the same code.

To be accessible in the `tensorflow`scope, `tf.reset_default_graph()` is defined and imported at the module level. Look at the import in the following `__init__`files and you should be able to track the `tf.reset_default_graph`definition up to the `tensorflow.python.framework.ops` module:

```
tensorflow/__init__.py
tensorflow/python/__init__.py
tensorflow/framework/framework_lib/__init__.py
```

and then 
`from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import get_default_graph`

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find the codes that you mentioned. In the [github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py), the `reset_default_graph()` just do `self.stack = []`.

Comment: My point is that they both call the same piece of code and are really the same method.